# Is it possible to make the trimmed borders by "border-radius" unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make the trimmed borders by "border-radius" unclickable, and also not detecting you are hovering over it?

Comment: Glad the answer worked! - when you have a moment - just edit this with some code so people can see your example should anything happen to your url since it's a good question. Best!

Comment: @MiaSno done! Added a jsFiddle too! :D

Comment: great - you done good! :)

Comment: Rather than including a fiddle with the solution in the question (which is already given in the answers), you should include a fiddle demonstrating the *problem*, so as not to confuse readers. That's what Mia Sno was trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make the wrapping div and a tags also have a border radius...

```
.blackground > div, .blackground > div a {
   border-radius: 100%;
}

.blackground > div a {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend just setting the `border-radius` on the containing element, and then giving it an `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: I think the reason I say the div as well is because in some browsers it will select the div as a block element with its native highlighting when you click it so better to shave it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make the `<a>` tag the one whose size changes, because that's the element that determines the click area.

So you can do

```
.backgroud > div > a {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then remove the border radius (if you want) on the actual image.